# How to make GridView ASP.NET control look like SharePoint List?

Tags: asp.net, css, sharepoint-2010, styling

Ive been developing a SharePoint WebPart. In this webpart there is a gridview used to display some information.

Due to business im required to give this gridview the look of a SharePoint list.

Is there anyone out there that has the styling to make the `GridView` ASP.Net control look like a SharePoint list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sharepoint server control **SPGridView** all css classes are already included [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Ejemplos-sobre-cmo-usar-el-69cd5f16) you can find how to use it.

For ASP.NET GridView control you can try the example below

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="ms-listviewtable">
    <HeaderRow CssClass="ms-viewheadertr ms-vhltr"/>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="ms-vh2" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="ms-itmhover" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="ms-alternating ms-itmhover" />
    <ControlStyle CssClass="ms-vb-title"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was help full